# How can I Update column value to Old value plus New value from other table using Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

How can I Update column value to Old value plus New value from other table using Trigger if that value has already have an entry?
What I wanted is something like the following. Notice the bold and italicized part.

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT
ON table_one FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_two(clmn_id, clmn_one) VALUES(NEW.clmn_id_fk,NEW.clmn_a)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clmn_one = VALUES(clmn_one + NEW.clmn_a);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the keyword VALUES from the ON DUPLICATE KEY:

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT
ON table_one FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_two(clmn_id, clmn_one) VALUES(NEW.clmn_id_fk,NEW.clmn_a)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fine_amount = clmn_one + NEW.clmn_a;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: For the update it works fine, but now it won't work for inserting new value.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: It simply won't insert new values unless it is an update. i.e. if the id doesn't exist no rows will be affected.

Comment: I got it if I set a default value for the column it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a select statement first, to check if it already exists.  If so, set variables to current values, then run an update that combines the old values (variables) and new values.  If the record doesn't already exist, run insert statement with current values.